# Having Oneg Shabbos with a non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, meal-seudah, leil-shabbat

I've heard some frum families not allowing non-Jews at the shabbos table for the Friday night meal, because oneg shabbos is specifically for Jews. Is there a source for this in any writings?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35129

Comment: Man... I just had this experience last Shabbos. I'm sure it can be very nice and good, but from personal experience it can be pretty difficult as well.

Answer (score 5):

As already discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/may-one-host-irreligious-guests-on-yom-tov) , `Halacha disallows inviting non Jews on Yom Tov (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 512:1). However, it is allowed on Shabbat, (Tur Orach Chaim 325).`

However, there are *technical issues* that need to be taken into account when inviting non-Jews to a Shabbat tables. Here are some issues:

- Wine: If it's not cooked (Mevushal) then you have an issue of Yayin Nesech; and you cannot have your guests touching the wine. Even having them drink wine in your glasses may pose halachic issues.
- Challa: There's a problem giving a non-Jew from the Challa used during Kiddush. See (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 41:4)

> ובשבת אפלו אם אוכל לבדו, מתר לבצוע כפי מה שצריך לכל הסעודה, מפני כבוד השבת, להראות חביבת סעודת שבת שחפץ לאכל בה הרבה. יש לאכל את הפרוסה שבצע עליה קדם שיאכל פת אחרת, והוא משום חבוב מצוה, כיון שברך עליה. וטוב לזהר שלא יתן ממנה **לנכרי** או לבהמה ועוף

- Benching: See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (44:18) that you would have to tweak the Nussach of the Birkat haMazon.

  > אם יש עובד כוכבים בבית כשמברך ברכת המזון, יאמר **אותנו בני ברית כלנו יחד**

Comment: Do you have a source for the part about wine glasses?  I haven't heard that before.  Thanks.

Comment: Why can't a non-Jew eat from the challah?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I don't know - the Kitzur doesn't say. And I don't recall seeing it anywhere.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I have not researched this, but I do recall from my youth that some people were careful to wash out the wine glasses before the maid touched them - maybe they were worried that the left over wine would get heated before it was diluted during the washing - and then render the cups unkosher. Just a guess.